# DjangoでSQL Serverのデータを読み込むときに、違うデータベース名が生成されてエラー

Tags: python, django, sql-server

`Django`で`SQL Server`からデータを読み出すプログラムを書いているのですが、実際のデータベース名と異なるオブジェクトが生成されてしまい、エラーになってしまいます。
エラーの内容は下記のとおりですが、'app_usertable'がなぜ生成されるのかわかりません。
rawメソッドを使っても同様のエラーになります。

('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]オブジェクト名 'app_usertable' が無効です。 (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]ステートメントを準備できませんでした。 (8180)")

models.py

```
class UserTable(models.Model): 
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32) 
   
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
data = UserTable.objects.filter(userid='sato')

for x in data:
    print(x.userid)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

マニュアルではなく`manage.py inspectdb` でモデルを構築してみてください。
多分、うまくいきます。